# iOS ideal image resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, image, ipad, server

I'm having a real hard time understanding this, but let's say I have an iOS app for both iPad and iPhone and I want to download an image from a server and display it in full screen.

I have read that the iPad pro has a resolution of `2732x2048` and if we want to display an image in fullscreen we would need to download the image with this size right? However, I also read that the image should never be over 300KB. I was not able to bring an image with this size under 2MB (I used JPEGmini for example to reduce size).

And I don't think that iPhone user would need to download such a huge image, so my question is: what resolution should my images be on the server and how can I manage to keep them in a rational file size. Also should I upload multiple images for different devices? If so, how many and at what resolutions?

Comment: It's hard to understand the 300KB limit without some context. Where did you read that?

Comment: One of the most obvious answer is - client app shall request image with resolution that fits screen:) And server can resample image on the fly or store them in all required resolutions

Comment: I have read something similar [here](https://forums.realmacsoftware.com/t/ideal-sizes-for-images-for-mobile-tablet-and-desktop/6926) in the first answer the third point

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the problem merely that you are holding incompatible beliefs? This is the belief that is giving you trouble:

> I also read that the image should never be over 300KB.

Let go of it.

Clearly it is right to say that the image should be no larger than needed for display. But an image to be shown as a 3x scale image on the iPad pro needs to be 2732x2048. So that's that.

(You could, alternatively, use an image 2/3 of that size and show it as a 2x scale image. It wouldn't look quite as good as the 3x scale image, but it might be acceptable.)

On a *smaller* device, yes, you should scale down the image in code, so that you are not holding in memory an image larger than needed for display. But in this case, you *need* the large image for display.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that the download time of the image could take quite a bit on slower internets, from what I have seen the images always download super fast and look good. Netflix app for example

Comment: You're the one who has made downloading the image a prerequisite of the question. And anyway, that has nothing to do with the question of ideal image size, which is what you asked about.

Comment: This is true, I just always thought there was a hidden secret to it :]. But apparently there isn't. It seems I will have to work with multiple images